# How do I mutate a StorageMap where the value is an enum?

Tags: rust, substrate

here is my StorageMap:

```
    #[pallet::getter(fn hotel_status)]
    /// Keeps track of what accounts own what Kitty.
    pub(super) type HotelStatus<T: Config> = StorageMap<
        _,
        Twox64Concat,
        T::AccountId,
        Gender,
    >;
```

I want to use `try_mutate` to either mutate the Gender because the AccountId already exists in the map, or insert a new entry. Here's the full extrinsic:

```
        #[pallet::weight(0)]
        pub fn activate_hotel(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            hotel: T::AccountId,
        ) -> DispatchResult {
            let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;
            log::info!("signer ID: {:?}.", sender);
            let hotel_status = <HotelStatus<T>>::get(&hotel);
            ensure!(hotel_status == Some(Gender::Active), <Error<T>>::HotelAlreadyActive);
            <HotelStatus<T>>::try_mutate(hotel, |status| {
                status = Gender::Active;
            }).map_err(|_| <HotelStatus<T>>::insert(hotel, Gender::Active));
            
            Ok(())
        }
```

the error I'm getting is

```
mismatched types
expected mutable reference, found enum `pallet::Gender`
note: expected mutable reference `&mut std::option::Option<pallet::Gender>`
                      found enum `pallet::Gender`rustc(E0308)
lib.rs(297, 14): expected mutable reference, found enum `pallet::Gender`
```

The substrate tutorials only give an example where the value is a vec and they try to push a new element onto it so I'm at a loss how to mutate an enum or primitive type (e.g. string, number).

Answer (score 1):

- `Gender::Active` is an enum
- `status` is `&mut Option<pallet::Gender>`

You can't assign `Gender::Active` to `status`, because there are not the same type. This is what the error message is telling you:

```rust
expected mutable reference `&mut std::option::Option<pallet::Gender>`
                      found enum `pallet::Gender`rustc(E0308)
```

To mutate the value behind the reference you need (in this case) to dereference it with `*` operator. `*status` type is `Option<pallet::Gender>`. You need to wrap `Gender::Active` in `Some` variant before assigning it to `*status`, since `Some(Gender::Active)` type is also `Option<pallet::Gender>`.

```rust
try_mutate(hotel, |status| {
  *status = Some(Gender::Active);
  Ok(())
}
```

`Ok(())` is required because the closure needs to return a `Result`

Comment: Sorry @Jerboas86 but can you also provide how to provide handling for the error case? the example from the tutorial seems to only apply for Vecs

`cannot infer type for type parameter 'E' declared on the associated function 'try_mutate'`

Comment: `try_mutate::<_, _, (), _>(hotel,...` if you specify with turbofish anotation does it work ?